# BeautifulSoup find_all() don't return XML

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup, lxml

I'm using the BeautifulSoup find_all() to get all the xmlo tags.

But when I try to iterate the method return, its a String!

I want all "GarantidorFielDepositario"(I get this with find_all()) tags and I want read the values from all children tags(like "TipoGarantidorFielDepositario","PrincipalGarantidor" and so on). tag after tag

```
(...)
  <fun:QtdMoeda>1</fun:QtdMoeda>
  <!--Optional:-->
  <fun:Observacao>teste</fun:Observacao>
  <!--Optional:-->
  <fun:GarantidorFielDepositario>
     <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
     <fun:GarantidorFielDepositario>
          <fun:TipoGarantidorFielDepositario>G</fun:TipoGarantidorFielDepositario>
          <!--Optional:-->
          <fun:CPFCNPJGarantidorFielDepositario>003.570.739-91</fun:CPFCNPJGarantidorFielDepositario>
          <!--Optional:-->
          <fun:PrincipalGarantidor>N</fun:PrincipalGarantidor>
          </fun:GarantidorFielDepositario>
   </fun:GarantidorFielDepositario>
</fun:GarantiaSaida>
```

in first moment, I just want print the children tags, but When I try, it dont show anything, and i think its because find_all() return a String, not an XML.

```
for cada in rootxml.find_all(retornoForEachVar):
    print '------'
    print cada.tag
```

For exemple, in this case, the variable "retornoForEachVar" has the value "GarantidorFielDepositario" and give to me all "GarantidorFielDepositario" tags. but the print cada.tag shows "none" in the screen.

Can find_all() bring me a XML Value?
do I have to parse the result to XML?

Comment: How did you create the `rootxml` soup? What's the parser?

Comment: rootxml = bs4.BeautifulSoup(open('rootRequest.xml').read(), 'xml')

Answer (score 0):

TO print the children, can do

```
for cada in rootxml.find_all(retornoForEachVar):
    children = cada.findChildren()
    for child in children: 
        print child
```

Comment: user8123426, here is the traceback: AttributeError: 'NavigableString' object has no attribute 'tag'